# How to switch between two windows in browser using Selenium java

Tags: java, testing, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with Selenium Automation. In this, When i click a link in a current window, a new window opens. I just want to switch the control to the new window. But i can't do this.**Actually the new window is an auto-generated one. That is, link will be generated dynamically.** Help me friends...

Answer (score 7):

To switch between windows we have method.

```
driver.switchTo().window("window name")
```

To get the different windows handle, we have method.

```
driver.getWindowHandles()
```

Example:

```
    File file = new File("G:\\Selenium\\All_Jars\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",file.getAbsolutePath() );
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    //Maximize the window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("http://www.rediff.com/");

    //Get all window handles
    Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    //count the handles Here count is=2
    System.out.println("Count of windows:"+allHandles.size());      

    //Get current handle or default handle
    String currentWindowHandle = allHandles.iterator().next();
    System.out.println("currentWindow Handle"+currentWindowHandle);

    //Remove first/default Handle
    allHandles.remove(allHandles.iterator().next());

    //get the last Window Handle
    String lastHandle = allHandles.iterator().next();
    System.out.println("last window handle"+lastHandle);

    //switch to second/last window, because we know there are only two windows 1-parent window 2-other window(ad window)
driver.switchTo().window(lastHandle);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. First you need to save the refrence to current window.

```
String parentWindow= driver.getWindowHandle();
```

The after having clicked the link, you need to switch to the other window.

```
List<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String curWindow : allWindows){
    driver.switchTo().window(curWindow);
}
```

This is where you perform operations on new window, finally closing it with

```
driver.close();
```

and switch back to parent window

```
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

Comment: Which part is not working. Showing some of your code will help us help you better. After you switch to the new windows handle, all operations will be performed on that window. It should work.

Comment: I remember having this problem and asking on #selenium in the IRC. What's intresting to try out was something pointed out to me. I edited the code so it can make clear, but you must guarantee while looping through the window handles that you are not actually switching to the current one.

Comment: Finally it works sir. I have used some code that i mentioned in my answer. Kindly have a look into it and give me your feedback sir. Thanks..!!  @SpartanElite

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer,
I used the below method to switch to the new window,

```
public String switchwindow(String object, String data){
        try {

        String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
        return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+ "Unable to Switch Window" + e.getMessage();
        }
        return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
        }
```

To move to parent window, i used the following code,

```
 public String switchwindowback(String object, String data){
            try {
                String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
                driver.close(); 
                //Switch back to original browser (first window)
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
                //continue with original browser (first window)
            }catch(Exception e){
            return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+ "Unable to Switch to main window" + e.getMessage();
            }
            return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
            }
```

Comment: I would recommend only switching to the window if it's not the current window. ie: Compare withHandleBefore with withHandle. Otherwise you're switching through all the windows unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

In an excerpt from a [getting started with selenium webdriver](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/blob/master/src/main/java/com/company/seleniumframework/AutomationTest.java#L233) project on github,

```
    /**
     * Waits for a window to appear, then switches to it.
     * @param regex Regex enabled. Url of the window, or title.
     * @return
     */
    public AutomationTest waitForWindow(String regex) {
        Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();

        for (String window : windows) {
            try {
                driver.switchTo().window(window);

                p = Pattern.compile(regex);
                m = p.matcher(driver.getCurrentUrl());

                if (m.find()) {
                    attempts = 0;
                    return switchToWindow(regex);
                }
                else {
                    // try for title
                    m = p.matcher(driver.getTitle());

                    if (m.find()) {
                        attempts = 0;
                        return switchToWindow(regex);
                    }
                }
            } catch(NoSuchWindowException e) {
                if (attempts <= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                    attempts++;

                    try {Thread.sleep(1);}catch(Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }

                    return waitForWindow(regex);
                } else {
                    fail("Window with url|title: " + regex + " did not appear after " + MAX_ATTEMPTS + " tries. Exiting.");
                }
            }
        }

        // when we reach this point, that means no window exists with that title..
        if (attempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
            fail("Window with title: " + regex + " did not appear after 5 tries. Exiting.");
            return this;
        } else {
            System.out.println("#waitForWindow() : Window doesn't exist yet. [" + regex + "] Trying again. " + attempts + "/" + MAX_ATTEMPTS);
            attempts++;
            return waitForWindow(regex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Switch's to a window that is already in existance.
     * @param regex Regex enabled. Url of the window, or title.
     * @return
     */
    public AutomationTest switchToWindow(String regex) {
        Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();

        for (String window : windows) {
            driver.switchTo().window(window);
            System.out.println(String.format("#switchToWindow() : title=%s ; url=%s",
                    driver.getTitle(),
                    driver.getCurrentUrl()));

            p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            m = p.matcher(driver.getTitle());

            if (m.find()) return this;
            else {
                m = p.matcher(driver.getCurrentUrl());
                if (m.find()) return this;
            }
        }

        fail("Could not switch to window with title / url: " + regex);
        return this;
    }
```

These are 2 custom functions to help you get started. Or you can check out that project from github to make your selenium projects better designed and easier.

These functions can switch to, or wait for (if it doesn't exist) a window with a certain title / url.

Comment: make sure that you change the "AutomationTest" variable's to `void`.  This method is proven, and works.  It's on your side that it is not working.  If you'd like a working copy, then download [the project that this is from](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/archive/master.zip) and import it into eclipse to see.

Comment: it's in the `SampleFunctionalTest` class under `src/tests/java`.  it starts at line `57`

Comment: Finally it works sir. I have used some code that i mentioned in my answer. Kindly have a look into it and give me your feedback sir. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best methods to switch in window using index and title. you can add in base class and use it frequently.

```
public  void switchToWindow(String windowTitle) {
    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String window : windows) {
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        if (driver.getTitle().contains(windowTitle)) {
            return;
        }
    }
}




  public void switchToWindow(int index) {
    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    int totalWin= windows.size();
    String winTitle = null;
    for(int i=0;i<totalWin;i++) {
        if(i==index) {
        winTitle = windows.toArray()[i].toString();
    }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(winTitle);
    System.out.println(winTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      Set <String> set = driver.getWindowHandles();
      Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
      String parentWindowId = it.next();
      String childWindowId = it.next();
      System.out.println(set);
      driver.switchTo().window(childWindowId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//to get the current/parent window

String parentWindowContact = driver.getWindowHandle();

//to switch to the new window from current/parent window

Set<String> handleswindow =driver.getWindowHandles();

for(String windowHandle : handleswindow)

{

   driver .switch To().window(windowHandle);

}

//to close the new window

driver.close();

//to switch back to the parent window

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowContact);
          o switch back to the parent window

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowContact);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    // fetch all windows before clicking on new window link.
    Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    // Click on link to open new window
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();  // link to open new window

    Set<String> updatedWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    updatedWindowHandles.removeAll(windowHandles);
    for (String window: updatedWindowHandles) {
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
    }
```