# How do I select a window in Selenium with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

While using the Firefox IDE, not quite everything is translatable. I'm having trouble with the following in particular:

```
ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=main | ]]
```

Can I just click on the window as I would any other button? My problem is that because this step is skipped, the automation test fails to click on the btnToDo element below it. I wonder if clicking the window is a prerequisite for clicking the button in this particular instance.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=main | ]]
driver.findElement(By.id("btnToDo")).click();
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"btnToDo"}
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.02 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'OLCZPR112319', ip: '10.99.133.66', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=C:\Users\MNXE\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7964_6827}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=49.0.2623.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: fda86deb9e9ba4514a3cd332a2bb73a3
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=btnToDo}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at ValidationTest.testValidation(ValidationTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

My error states that the button does not exist but it clearly does. After clicking "btnLogin", I am taken to a new page. Here, it seems the test is unable to locate the new "btnToDo".

Comment: http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-switch-control-to-pop-up-window.html

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how I'd do this in the context of my question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like clicking on btnLogin, new window is populating as per provided recording code. So here we need to switch to that new window to interact with elements in that new window. So that switch window recorded in Selenium IDE is not translated to WebDriver.

In webDriver there is concept getWindowHandles which provides to all web browsers opened by it. So first collect those handles and iterate to new one which is opened, then switch to that. Once work in that window is done, if required you need to switch back to first window to interact elements in first window.

for code please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117747/how-to-switch-between-two-windows-in-browser-using-selenium-java)

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: may i know why you are using selectLinkOpeninNewTab in sendkeys? and also did you tried like print command after this  driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle); to cross check driver moved to new window or not. i think instead of contains in "!popupHandle.contains(mainWindowHandle)" we can use equals here. plz try once

Comment: The popupHandle and mainWindowHandle are the same, even after clicking the btnLogin link to go to the next page.

Comment: hoo.. two web pages may be as tabs displaying physically and also see s.size two or not..

Comment: I got rid of tab pop up. Instead it's just a link but the problem is the same.

Comment: can i have website if possible or similar example to see that?

Comment: I don't have a specific example I can show you but the process is fairly straight forward. Fill the login form with user and password, click "login". On the next page, click a link ``<a id="btnToDo" href="xyz.html">``

Comment: got it..then if target=_blank is there then new browser will comes..so here not in html code. so no need to use windows hangles or switch etc.. if still fails without switch then try once switch to "main" as IDE recording