# How to change browser instance in selenium using Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, pom.xml

How to change browser instance in Selenium- Java? WebDriver could not locate the elements on the screen after clicking on second webpage

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117747/how-to-switch-between-two-windows-in-browser-using-selenium-java) or [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button) answers might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

// First store the current window instance

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

// After your click operation which opens the new window

// Below code Switches instance to the new window

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
```

}

// If you want to switch back to the original window

```
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```